# In determining shape from line, what is special about the lines I've shown in these drawings by Ken Reid?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm interested in the way artists use lines to indicate shape in drawings. Strictly speaking, my question is about human vision — how our brains interpret certain lines — but I'm asking it here because those working in shape perception might be able to suggest an answer. It concerns what my visual system thinks it's seeing in the arrowed parts of drawings such as these, and how this relates to the geometrical properties of the objects and their projection onto two dimensions:

[image: Frame 2, row 2]
     
[image: Frame 1, row 3]

**Before continuing with the question, I should add that after I posted it, "D.W." put it on hold *without consulting me*, on the grounds that it's not about computer science. I refer him or her to http: //gfx.cs.princeton.edu/proj/ld3d/ , "Line Drawings of 3D Shapes". To quote from the top of that page:**

> **This site describes recent research on line drawings of 3D shapes, including studies on how artists create drawings and how people interpret drawings.**
>
> **So far, this work involves two studies. The first, "Where Do People Draw Lines?," investigates how artists' drawings of 3D shapes correlate with the mathematical properties of the shapes, and known computer graphics line drawing techniques. The second, "How Well Do Line Drawings Depict Shape?," examines how people interpret line drawings, both hand-drawn and computer-generated, and when depiction succeeds and fails.**

**Note the bit about how drawings correlate with the mathematical properties of the shapes drawn. This is related to the cues that humans and programs use to infer 3-d shape from 2-d projections, which in turn are related to the way that 3-d shapes look when projected onto 2-d surfaces. An excellent writeup of the latter topic is given in http: //www.gestaltrevision.be/pdfs/koenderink/Shape.pdf , "Shadows of Shape" by Jan Koenderink, a mathematician and psychologist known for his researches on visual perception, computer vision, and geometry. I hope what I've said in bold shows that my question is relevant to computing, but if not, D.W., please ask a computer-vision expert.**

The drawings are by Ken Reid. He drew for the *Beano* and other comics, and was known for strips such as *Frankie Stein*, *Queen of the Seas*, and *The Nervs*. His faces were often grotesque, with protrusions such as chins and Adam's apples standing out clearly despite being drawn with very few lines. There are examples of his work on Lew Stringer's blog at http://lewstringer.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/ken-reid-genius.html , and a copy of a *The Nervs* strip at http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_448y6kVhntg/RhIjT_1lF0I/AAAAAAAAA3I/KtvcxEIE3F8/s1600-h/nervs_pg1.jpg . What interests me is why the lines he drew are so effective. What is the visual system interpreting them as?

The images above are from the above-linked strip. In the first image, the back of the knee, there's an upward-curving line above a short vertical above two downward-curving lines. The higher downward-curving line is presumably the contour of the lower leg. It's less obvious what the downward-curving line below it is, or whether it corresponds to any physical feature. Nevertheless, it certainly helps in giving a sense of three-dimensional form.

Similarly, in the second image, some of the three upward-curving lines could be folds where the chin presses back against itself. But is the visual system interpreting them all as folds? I don't know, but again, they readily give a sense of form. Another example is here, from the very first frame in that strip:

[image: Frame 1, row 1]

As I said at the start, those working in shape perception might have an answer. I'd also be interested to hear from anyone whose vision programs happen to fit Reid's conventions so well that they can actually deduce from those drawings the shapes he intended.

By the way, I and other readers have noticed that Reid's drawings seem very "intense". As one reader commented in a blog, "they seem to enter the subconscious and stick there for the rest of your life". Why? That's probably outside the scope of computer vision, but not necessarily. It might be that some classes of line, e.g. closely-spaced lines curving around a cylinder, happen to affect us particularly strongly. So it would be useful to know if there's something special about the geometry of Reid's lines.

Comment: I fail to see where this question takes or requires a computer *science* perspective. It's about visual perception of humans, so it should be on [biology.SE] or [cogsci.SE], as far as I can tell.

Comment: [Also posted on CogSci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/13088).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: D.W.,Raphael: please see the section I added in bold. Note the links therein. There are now many papers in computer vision and computer graphics about the cues artists use to indicate shape. There are even programs that try to imitate human artists: see e.g. http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/goodlines.eg2003.pdf , "A Few Good Lines: Suggestive Drawing of 3D Models" by Mario Costa Sousa and Przemyslaw Prusinkiewicz. I suspect there's something special about the geometry of Reid's form-indicating lines. A specialist in shape perception would be able to tell me. This _is_ computer vision.

Comment: D.W.: I posted here as well as on CogSci. SE because the readers have different knowledge. Here, I'll likely find answers concerning the geometrical properties of Reid's drawings. Or I might stumble across an expert who happens to use exactly these cues in their vision program! From CogSci, I'm more likely to get neural algorithms, and information about experiments on human perception: e.g. illusions that demonstrate how sometimes one cue dominates and sometimes another does. Both are relevant — but I wouldn't expect many people to be expert in both. I'd be silly to neglect either.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  However, I'd like to direct you to [the link I shared earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  You posted two nearly-identical questions.  I'm afraid that even if there are two sites that could provide interesting answers and where the question would be on-topic on both, it's still not allowed to post the same question on both.  I do understand that you would prefer to ask on both sites, and that readers might have different knowledge, and you might get different kinds of answers.  But we have our policy about cross-posting for a reason.

Comment: Rather than adding a bunch of bold to justify that it's on-topic here, I would suggest that it'd be more helpful to edit the question to focus on some aspect of your question that is specific to computer vision / CS.  Can you narrow your question down to some narrower aspect of the topic that is clearly squarely within computer science, to minimize overlap with the existing question on CogSci?

Comment: From [Top Down and Bottom Up perception](http://www.simplypsychology.org/perception-theories.html) we can assume that when we have contours - the information is easier to acquire, some details are lost anyway, some are ambigous, so giving the "right" lines eases the process. Here you can ask about how to retreive properties of curves. Ideal experiment to provide you useful insight would require some picture, Eye Tracker, and image of picture made to be outlined version of the orignal - capture both and check how it was processed. Obviously the main lines are continous and smooth.

Comment: I had once lecture about "sad curves" but this is just getting worse. I do such crazy things, but I do not have proper Eye Tracker to check it. I think you shold separate checking for properties from computer vision (which does not cover human vision) from perception and rather do not imply that something so interesting for you is equally interesting to others. There are differences amongst the people and even between you and from year before. Who is CV expert anyway? I can assure you that imprint (the memory that stays with you forever) is possible only to infants. No lines can make it happen

Comment: Sorry to comment like this, but I would like you to reconsider some statements, give your objective that is doable - if you want anybody to share Data Mining experience with you from intersection of computer vision and psychology at once - this is a bit too much to give straight away, not many people do both (I hope), well fortunatelly I do, but still this is CS division, and your objective right now is "which mathematical property makes Reid's drawings so special" - nobody can answer it - this is special for you, maybe more people thinks the same, but on different basis, PDF -not that special